# Trouble shooting audio - soundcard issue

Tags: ubuntu, audio, raspberry-pi, sound-card, alsa

I just booted up a raspberry pi using this image: `ubuntu-16.04.3-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img`
It seems that the sound card is not detected or configured 'out of the box'

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /proc/asound/cards 
--- no soundcards ---
```

I do not have much experience with kernel modules or the tools used to load/remove them. I did learn that the the module for the raspberry pis sound card was not loaded though so I tried:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# modprobe snd_bcm2835
```

Seems to load fine:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lsmod |grep snd
snd_bcm2835            32768  0
snd_pcm               106496  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    81920  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

I also made sure `alsa-utils` was installed. But I still cannot play sound and still get the following results from these commands:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /proc/asound/cards 
--- no soundcards ---
```

-

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
```

-

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# play nice.ambient.mp3
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
play FAIL formats: can't open output file `default': snd_pcm_open error: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct procedure for ensuring the soundcard works for this image and that it works from boot?